# Contact form downloads when submitted

Tags: php, html, forms, contacts

My contact form downloads the `php` file on submit everytime, not sure why this happens but my code is correct and have used this code on other websites and it works fine.

Here's my `HTML`:

```
 <form id="ContactForm" action="contact.php" method="post">
 <div>
 <div class="wrapper">
 <div class="bg">
 <input class="input" type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" tabindex="1">
 </div>
  Name: </div>
 <div class="wrapper">
 <div class="bg">
 <input class="input" type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" tabindex="1">
 </div>
 Email: </div>
 <div class="wrapper">
 <div class="bg2">
 <textarea cols="1" rows="1" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
 </div>
 Message: </div>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button" /> </div>
 </form>
```

Here's the `PHP`:

```
<?php
$field_name = $_POST['name'];
$field_email = $_POST['email'];
$field_message = $_POST['message'];

$mail_to = 'email address';
$subject = 'Message from a website visitor '.$field_name;

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');
    window.location = 'contact.html';
</script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    alert('Message failed.');
    window.location = 'contact.html';
</script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Please note: I deliberately took out the email address after `$mail_to`

Anyone have this problem before and manage to find out what it is?

Comment: Check the use of quotes and double quotes while setting the body and header.

Comment: Do other PHP scripts work on this website?

Comment: Does your host support PHP? Does `phpinfo()` work?

Comment: @Pieter There's no problem with those at all, I use it the same way on other sites

Comment: @Barmar This is the only PHP script on this website

Comment: @AmalMurali not sure how exactly to use `phpinfo()` do I simply put the file into my server space?

Comment: @RymanHolmes: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in a file with `.php` extension.

Comment: Make sure the server is configured to run .php files with PHP.

Comment: @AmalMurali and where do I upload that file?

Comment: The same place as your contact.php file.

Comment: I have created and uploaded the `phpinfo.php` file to the server and tried to call it from a browser however it downloads this the same way aswell

Comment: Then your server doesn't have PHP support enabled. Check the server configuration.

Comment: @Barmar How do I check that? I'm with 123 reg?

Comment: I've just tested this and works fine, it doesn't download it.

Answer (score 1):

That usually indicates that PHP is not installed or not running on that web server.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to install php onto your server (if you have access to the terminal):

sudo apt-get install php5

sudo apache2ctl restart

Best way to check if you have php installed is by creating a new php file and calling it test.php or something:

```
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
```

If you have php installed, it'll show you your current php settings. If not, it means you dont have it installed.